# iOS keychain - who or what can access it

Tags: access-control, ios, keychain

I have an iOS app that needs to be able to upload data in the background, and so also when the device is locked. To achieve background uploading I use information stored in the key chain. Therefore I can only set key chain access to be when first unlocked on this device only, to be able to access it in the background and when locked.

In simple terms who can access that key chain information when the device is unlocked. I'm not worried about a professional forensic hacker, but someone with a tool which can access the device files system, such as iExplorer.

Could they access this information if they found my device unlocked, if not, what is stopping them accessing it.

Comment: This might be an iOS-specific question because it has to do with the internal architecture

Comment: If you'd ask that question on StackOverflow, I'd be able to answer it based on the documentation that Apple provides. But since you post it here in security stackexchange I understand you want a real security answer. No one (except an Apple employee) will be able to answer your question as the technical details of the implementation are not published by Apple. We can only supposed that there's something related to the app's provisioning profile that wouldn't allow other apps to access it but we can't support that claim from the documentation we have.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused, is the keychain vulnerable when the device is not locked? Does this mean if unlocked someone could plug it into a computer and read all the data?